# Tailwind and over-lapping images?

Tags: tailwind-css

not too sure how I would go about making this effect using tailwind classes, can someone help me out?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can position the images in an `absolute` position.

```html
<div class="relative h-[500px] w-[500px] border border-dashed">
  <div class="absolute right-10 top-10 h-64 w-64 bg-green-500"></div>
  <div class="absolute bottom-20 right-40 h-40 w-40 bg-orange-500"></div>
  <div class="absolute left-16 top-20 h-48 w-48 bg-blue-500"></div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/TM1YauZ5Dr